# Magento 2.0 reset/restore the home-site

Tags: magento2, home, websites

Hey i deleted my homepage and thought it would be easy to create a new one.
But i cant find any solutions how to do this. I found many threads about this Problem in Magento1 but not one for magento 2.
How can i create a new HomePage?

Comment: are you want to create a new  page and assign it as home page ??

Comment: exactly ive created the page already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Navigate **Content->Pages** and **click on add new pag**e.

```
exp: Page Title =   Home page
     URL Key    =   home
     Store View =   Store View
```

Navigate **Stores->Configuration->web->Default pages** under **CMS Home Page** select the page from drop down (You will see the page title)  and click on **save config** button clear your cache and refresh the page.

Done!